# Why EF Core generates only parent(Game) properties updating despite State=Modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
var game = _context.Games
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
            .Include(x => x.PlatformTypes)
            .Include(x => x.Genres)
            .Include(x => x.Publisher)
            .First();
        
game.Description = "New Description";
_context.Attach(game).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();

// CONVERTS TO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Games] SET [Description] = @p0, [Discontinued] = @p1, [Key] = 
@p2, [Name] = @p3, [Price] = @p4, [PublisherId] = @p5, [UnitsInStock] = 
@p6
WHERE [Id] = @p7;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

1. got entity Game with nested entities - State = Detached, no tracking
2. updated Game description - State = Detached, No tracking
3. attached Game to context - State =  Unchaged for everything inside Game, Tracking started
4. Set State to modified - State = Modified for everything inside Game

When SaveChanges, EF Core generates only Game's properties(excluding nested entites) update query. Why it does not generate updating of nested entities despite all nested entities in Entry have IsModified = true?

[image: modified is true in published]

Comment: `_context.Attach(game).State` ???? The `game` object came from the DbContext, it's *already* tracked. If any of its prorperties are modified, it will be marked `Modified` as well. You didn't post any code that modifies either the root or any child objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is a sneaky `AsNoTracking()` I didn't see as well :)

Comment: @Progman there's the problem then.

Comment: @MaksJok Remove `AsNoTracking()` and don't try to manually attach the object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How do you know that all nested entities have "IsModified = true"?

Comment: sorry, not `_context.Description` but `game.Description`

Comment: @Progman they don't because they weren't modified so they don't need to be saved. Unless the OP posts code that actually modifies any of them, there's no reason for them to be updated

Comment: @MaksJok remove `AsNoTracking()` and post any code that modifies the child entities. You wouldn't need `Attach` if you didn't use `AsNoTracking`. The child entities aren't tracked just because you used `Attach` on the parent.

Comment: @Progman, evaluation of it via `_context.Entry(game).Properties` or `_context.Entry(game).Collections` and it has nested prop isModified that is true

Comment: I know how to write it with a good approach without asnotracking and Attach. I do not understand why it works so and does not generate update query for nested entities

Comment: @MaksJok what does this matter? The bug is the use of `AsNoTracking()`. That's meaningless in this case. Besides, you didn't post any code that modifies the child entities, so why should *anything* else be saved? And what do you expect would be saved? It would be the same values that are already stored

Comment: `does not generate update query for nested entities` because they aren't modified. Tracking starts after `Attach`, so any changes made to them earlier are lost. The only reason `game` is saved is because you explicitly mark it as modified with `.State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, i understand that it is meaningless. I only want to understand why we set State = Modified and it generates updates only for Game's props but excludes nested PlatformTypes,Genres, Publisher

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, but i modified only Description. Why it generates update for all other game's props excluding nested entities

Comment: @MaksJok because someone blindly added `AsNoTracking` and changes were no longer detected. Someone tried to cover up the bug instead of fixing it with `Attach().State =...` without realizing that this only applied to the specific object

Comment: @MaksJok on the contrary, the code says that the *entire* object is modified. `AsNoTracking()` means that EF no longer tracks changes to the object. It has no idea about the `Description` change. When you used `_context.Attach(game).State = EntityState.Modified;` you told EF that this is a modified object that needs to be saved. EF has no idea what the previous state was, precisely because `AsNoTracking` is used. So it has to save everything

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, so you are going to say that Attach(game) only starts tracking of Game props excluding nested entities?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, i set state to modified, it should mark object and all nested entities as dirty. So, they also should be updated. But i have only game's props(excluding nested entities) updated

Comment: No, I'm saying that you only marked `game` as `Modified`, not the *related* entities.  Even if all of the entities are tracked, only one of them is marked `Modified`

Comment: `it should mark object and all nested entities as dirty.` no it shouldn't. Just because one entity is modified doesn't mean others are modified as well. If you modify an `OrderItem` it doesn't mean that `Order` and `Customer` are modified as well. Or vice versa. Modifying the address in an `Order` doesn't mean the `OrderItem` instances have changed

Comment: @MaksJok Please [edit] your question to include the [mcve], which shows that the nested objects are marked as `IsModified`. I did a quick test and the `IsModified` flag for the nested entry properties are all still set to the default value `false`, as expected. EF will therefore not send any `UPDATE` queries. Keep in mind that `.State=...` only change the state of that entity, not the whole object tree.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, seems logically

Comment: @MaksJok The screenshot shows that the navigation property `game.Publisher` is marked as "modified". It does not say or mean, that the `Publisher` object which is referenced in that navigation property is modified. In fact, if you check the `TargetEntity.State` property, it will show `Unchanged`.

Comment: @MaksJok if you want to see the publisher's status use `var pubEntry=_context.Entry(game.Publisher);` and check its properties

Answer (score 1):

The [`State` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.state?view=efcore-5.0) on the `EntityEntry` object (which is returned by the [`Attach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-5.0) method) changes only the state of that specific object, not for the whole object tree accessible via navigation properties. Check the documentation of that property:

> This method sets only the state of the single entity represented by this entry. It does not change the state of other entities reachable from this one.

So your `game` instance is marked as "modified", but the other navigation properties (like `Publisher`) are not.

Comment: But why publisher's IsModified is True in the screenshot?

Comment: That's for the `game.Publisher` property, not the `Publisher` instance which is referenced.

Comment: @MaksJok The screenshots you posted don't show what you assume. The docs go to great lengths to stress that things *don't* behave this way

Comment: @MaksJok `Publisher` is a separate entity. You'll have to find that `Publisher`'s entry. Have you tried retrieving the `EntityEntry` for the publisher?

Answer (score 1):

The code fails because `AsNoTracking()` tells EF to *not* track any changes to the object. This means EF has no idea that `Description` has changed. The rest is based on the mistaken assumption that all related entities will be marked `Modified`

`game` is saved only because it's attached and *explicitly* marked as modified.
`_context.Attach(game)` tells EF to start tracking the arbitrary (detached) object `game` and any reachable entity as **Unchanged**. As far as EF knows, this object may have come from a POST call, or a JSON file. From the [DbContext.Attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Attach__1___0_) docs :

> Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using the Unchanged state by default.

The method returns the EntityEntry only for the `game` entity

> **Returns** The EntityEntry for the entity. The entry provides access to change tracking information and operations for the entity.

The `Attach` doc page explicitly says `Use State to set the state of only a single entity.`

At this point, the `game` entity is Unchanged. The code then tells EF that `game` is modified. The line

```
_context.Attach(game).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

is equivalent to :

```
var gameEntry=_context.Attach(game);
gameEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

The [EntityEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry?view=efcore-5.0) tracks only a single entity:

> Provides access to change tracking information and operations for a given entity.

Its [State property docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.state?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_State) explicitly say that :

> This method sets only the state of the single entity represented by this entry. It does not change the state of other entities reachable from this one.

At this point EF only knows it has a Modified entity, it doesn't know what was modified. Since `AsNoTracking` was used, there's no previous state to compare to. EF *has* to save all the object's properties.

None of the related entities is modified though, so EF doesn't have to UPDATE or INSERT those. Even if they were modified before `Attach`, EF wouldn't know it because none of them is marked `Modified`. EF can only track modifications made after `Attach`.

To fix the problem *remove* `AsNoTracking()` :

```
var game = _context.Games
            .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
            .Include(x => x.PlatformTypes)
            .Include(x => x.Genres)
            .Include(x => x.Publisher)
            .First();
        
game.Description = "New Description";

_context.SaveChanges();
```

**About the screenshot**

The screenshot **doesn't** show the `EntityEntry`s for the related entities like `Publisher`, it shows the internal change tracking table for `game`'s members. To find the status of the `Publisher` you'll have to pull *its* entry with [DbContext.Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Entry_System_Object_) and check its status :

```
var publisherEntry=_context.Entry(game.Publisher);
Console.WriteLine(publisherEntry.State);
```